# How to remove code duplication in this java code

Tags: java, foreach

Using the same for-each loop inside 2 different  method, is there any way to reduce code duplication here?

1st code

```
for (AjaxControlBean controlBean : requestData.getControls()) {
    if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(controlBean.getId(), controlBean.getName()) || "repeat".equalsIgnoreCase(controlBean.getType())) 
    {
        continue;
    }
    FormInstanceControl control = formInstance.getControl(controlBean.getId());
    if (control == null) {
       control = new FormInstanceControl();
       control.setFormInstance(formInstance);
       control.setControlId(controlBean.getId());
       formInstance.putControl(control);
    }
    if (controlBean.getValues() != null) {
       if (control.getData() != null)
          control.getData().clear();
       else
          control.setData(new ArrayList<FormInstanceData>());

       for (String value : controlBean.getValues()) {
           FormInstanceData data = new FormInstanceData();
           data.setControl(control);
           data.setType(FormInstanceData.TYPE_TEXT);
           data.setText(value);
           control.getData().add(data);
       }
    }
}
```

2nd code

```
for (AjaxControlBean controlBean : requestData.getControls()) {
     if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(controlBean.getId(), controlBean.getName()) || "repeat".equalsIgnoreCase(controlBean.getType())) {
         continue;
     }
     FormInstanceControl control = formInstance.getControl(controlBean.getId());
     if (control == null) {
        control = new FormInstanceControl();
        control.setFormInstance(formInstance);
        control.setControlId(controlBean.getId());
        formInstance.putControl(control);
     }
     if (controlBean.getValues() != null) {
        if (control.getData() != null) {
            control.getData().clear();
        } 
        else 
        {
            control.setData(new ArrayList<FormInstanceData>());
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (String value : controlBean.getValues()) {
            FormInstanceData data = new FormInstanceData();
            data.setControl(control);
            data.setType(FormInstanceData.TYPE_TEXT);
            data.setText(value);
            data.setIdx(i++);
            control.getData().add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

the only difference it has is the data.setIdx(i++);  Please let me know if there is anything i can do to reduce number of lines

Comment: Is it in the same class? Why is this tagged "ajax"?

Comment: In the first snippet, would it break anything if you set the Index there, too? Or is it just ignored in that case?

Comment: it is in the same class

Comment: You could factor out a Method that takes a `FormInstanceControl` and a `AjaxControlBean` as arguments. Then you've got all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could factor out a method that takes a `FormInstanceControl` and a `AjaxControlBean` as arguments. Then you've got all you need:

```
private void addBeanData( FormInstanceControl control, AjaxControlBean controlBean) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String value : controlBean.getValues()) {
        FormInstanceData data = new FormInstanceData();
        data.setControl(control);
        data.setType(FormInstanceData.TYPE_TEXT);
        data.setText(value);
        data.setIdx(i++);
        control.getData().add(data);
     }
}
```

This assumes, the first snippet doesn't break if the Idx is set, even if it's not done there in the original code.

Usage: Where before you had the for-loops, you just do `addBeanData( control, controlBean );`

Comment: Hey can i do this also ? Idx is not that important so can i have above two codes in one method, by passing these parameters private void addBeanData(AjaxDataBean requestData, FormInstance formInstance) { for (AjaxControlBean controlBean : requestData.getControls())

Comment: Basically: If you have two pieces of code that are identical, you can make it a method. If that piece of code "uses" something, pass it as parameter. That's the gist of it.